Prometheus query from multiple jobs
I have 2 jobs in Prometheus:

a ping check job that I use to check if the computers are reachable by ping
- job_name: 'ping_check_windows'
  metrics_path: /probe
  params:
    module: [icmp_ping]  # Use the module defined in Blackbox Exporter config
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['192.168.0.90','192.168.0.85','192.168.0.155','192.168.0.56','192.168.0.232','192.168.0.96',
                '192.168.0.5','192.168.0.95','192.168.0.98','192.168.0.35','192.168.0.114','192.168.0.52',
                '192.168.0.78','192.168.0.40','192.168.0.60','192.168.0.176','192.168.0.89','192.168.0.1',
                '192.168.0.213','192.168.0.57','192.168.0.54','192.168.0.27','192.168.0.22','192.168.0.28',
                '192.168.0.106','192.168.0.92','192.168.0.68','192.168.0.209','192.168.0.191','192.168.0.188',
                '192.168.0.81','192.168.0.112','192.168.0.192','192.168.0.44','192.168.0.253','192.168.0.125',
                '192.168.0.201','192.168.0.3','192.168.0.99','192.168.0.221','192.168.0.189','192.168.0.180',
                '192.168.0.185','192.168.0.193','192.168.0.48','192.168.0.111','192.168.0.42','192.168.0.166',
                '192.168.0.79','192.168.0.63']
  relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__address__]
      target_label: __param_target
    - source_labels: [__param_target]
      target_label: instance
    - target_label: __address__
      replacement: 192.168.0.204:9115


a Seafile check job
- job_name: 'Seafile'
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['192.168.0.196:8123']



In Prometheus I run these queries:

The query probe_success{instance=~"192.168.0.*"} == 1 returns
...
probe_success{instance="192.168.0.35", job="ping_check_windows"}
1
...

The query label_replace(seafile_info{peer_ip=~"192.168.0."}, "instance", "$1", "peer_ip", "(.)")`
returns
...
seafile_info{instance="192.168.0.35", job="Seafile", peer_ip="192.168.0.35"}
1733241991
...


But the query
probe_success{instance=~"192.168.0.*"} == 1
and ignoring(job)
label_replace(seafile_info{peer_ip=~"192.168.0.*"}, "instance", "$1", "peer_ip", "(.*)")

return empty. Why? I understand that the jobs don't have the same timestamps, they are not collected at the exact same time but I don't know how to fix this.

Timestamps shouldn't matter as long as they are within 5 minutes from each other. You problem is peer_ip in the second metric. Add it to ignore also.

I spoke with Chat GPT about this for 5 hours with no result, and your suggestion solved the problem. Thank you.

Well, what can I say... Hope this will be a lesson about usefulness and correctness of its answers.
